# How to test Rollbar installation for iOS with test crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rollbar

I am trying to test that my installation of Rollbar is working, and I have this in my `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"Everything is ok. This is just a test crash."];
});

// Also tried this to simulate bad access
strcpy(0, "bla");
```

Except it does not show up in the dashboard.

However, this does:

```
[Rollbar infoWithMessage:@"Testing the install"];
```

Is there a way to simulate a test crash that will actually send to the dashboard? Appreciated. Although I do find this situation to be very strange as Rollbar should simply be getting all of these errors.

**UPDATE (Oct 15, 2015)**

I actually emailed Rollbar and they have been working on fixing this problem for a few weeks now. Perhaps the new iOS fudged their service?

**UPDATE (May 15, 2016)**

They still never got back to me about this. I suppose they had some higher priority issues to deal with!

Answer (score 0):

With iOS you have to start the application back up again to see anything in the dashboard. Rollbar saves up errors and notices and sends them in a batch at startup.

Comment: I did perform that step, and still nothing. I emailed Rollbar and they have been working on this problem for weeks now.